# Is there any way to make a C++ Switch Statement loop back to the first case?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

OK, here is a simple code example:

```
    char answer;
    cin >> answer;
    switch(answer)
    {
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            inventory[0] = "Short Sword";
            cout << "\nYou place the Rusty Battle Axe in the chest.";
            break;

        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            inventory[0] = "Rusty Battle Axe";
            cout << "\nYou leave the Short Sword in the chest.";
            break;

        default :
            cout << "\nThat was an invalid response.";
    }
```

Obviously I could pull my hair out with a while(answer != 'Y' || answer !=...) But is there a more elegant way of simply returning to the first case after executing the default case? So if a user enters the wrong letter, I simply ask them the question again until they type an acceptable response?

No this isn't homework or anything. I'm working through Dawson's C++ Game Programming book, and I wanted to jazz up the program example a little by allowing the user to keep or trade an item. I got all that working beautifully, but if a wrong response is entered it just shows the contents of the inventory and exits. I wanted to get that right. Force the user to enter a correct response, then show the updated inventory afterwards.

Appreciate the help!

**UPDATE!**
You have all given me so many different approaches to this - I really appreciate it! I admit I probably did not design this switch statement correctly and I apologize for the contradiction. I will try each of your suggestions and post back here, choosing one as answer. Thank you!

OK, I have just gone through all of your answers, trying most of them with my code. I have chosen the simplest, most elegant solution as the answer to my question. But you all have helped me to see different ways of looking at this, and I understand so much more about switch statements now. Using it in fact in place of a while loop in a tutorial I am following right now at YouTube by user What's A Creel?

I really appreciate all your help! I feel that I have really accomplished a lot in my programming practice today. You guys (and gals) are all awesome!

**UPDATED AND COMPLETE CODE:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// This program displays a hero's inventory

int main()
{
    const int MAX_ITEMS = 4;
    string inventory[MAX_ITEMS];

    int numItems = 0;
    inventory[numItems++] = "Rusty Battle Axe";
    inventory[numItems++] = "Leather Armor";
    inventory[numItems++] = "Wooden Shield";

    cout << "Inventory:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < numItems; ++i)
    {
        cout << inventory[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nYou open a chest and find a Lesser Healing Potion.";
    inventory[numItems++] = "Lesser Healing Potion";

    cout << "\nInventory\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < numItems; ++i)
    {
        cout << inventory[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nYou also find a Short Sword.";
    if(numItems < MAX_ITEMS)
    {
        inventory[numItems++] = "Short Sword";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nYou have too many items and can't carry another.";
        cout << "\nWould you like to trade the " << inventory[0] << " for the Short Sword? ";
    }

    while (true)
    {
        char answer;
        cin >> answer;
        switch(answer)
        {
            case 'y':
            case 'Y':
                inventory[0] = "Short Sword";
                cout << "\nYou place the Rusty Battle Axe in the chest." << endl;
                break;

            case 'n':
            case 'N':
                inventory[0] = "Rusty Battle Axe";
                cout << "\nYou leave the Short Sword in the chest." << endl;
                break;

            default:
                cout << "\nThat was an invalid response!";
                cout << "\nWould you like to trade the " << inventory[0] << " for the Short Sword? ";
                continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    cout << "\nInventory:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < numItems; ++i)
    {
        cout << inventory[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put the switch in a function that returns a bool and use that in your condition.

Comment: Er... Your question contradicts itself. You state that you want to ask the user for input again if the initial answer was invalid. But the user input is read *outside* of switch. Why then do you want to return to the first option of switch then???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a one-shot loop that breaks at the end and use `continue` to jump back to the top:

```
while(true)
{
    switch(...) {
        //...
        default:
            continue;
    }
    break;
};
```

Perhaps a nicer way is to define a set of valid letters, especially if you'll do this kind of thing everywhere in your code:

```
char GetChoice( const string & prompt, const string & valid_choices )
{
    while( cin.good() )
    {
        cout << prompt << " " << flush;

        char c;
        if( !cin.get(c) ) break;

        size_t pos = valid_choices.find(toupper(c));
        if( pos != string::npos ) return valid_choices[pos];
    }
    return 0;  // Error condition.
}
```

And use like this:

```
switch( GetChoice("Do you want cake?", "YN") )
{
    case 'Y':
        cout << "Cake for you.\n";
        break;
    case 'N':
        cout << "No cake for you.\n";
        break;
    case 0:
        exit(1);      // Error occurred
}
```

Comment: Your GetChoice example is a really advanced answer and I think it may be too advanced for my code. I have saved this page and will play with this later, but i need to be sure I understand what is going on here when I try it. Not quite there yet I'm afraid, although I get the gist of what the code does. Thank you!

Comment: Your while(true) answer however is the most elegant and simple so far. It works perfectly right out of the box with my code. AWESOME!

Answer (score 2):

Well, add a loop and it will "loop back" wherever you want.

Note that the entire body of `switch` is just one long statement with labels in it. It works as any other statement, once you entered it through one of the labels. Just like an ordinary C++ statement will not "loop back" for you by itself unless you make it a cycle or use `goto`, neither will the body of `switch` "loop back" for you by itself.

So, if you want to transfer control back - use the appropriate language construct. You can inject `goto` right into the body of that statement and it will work as usual.

```
switch(answer)
{
    case 'y':
    case 'Y':
    FIRST_OPTION:
        ...
        break;

    default :
        ...;
        goto FIRST_OPTION; // Jump to first option
}
```

You might also want to take a look at [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) for a more intricate example of control transfer inside `switch` statement.

However, your question seems to contradict itself. You state that you want to ask the user for input again, if the answer was invalid. But the user input is requested and accepted outside of `switch`. Why do you say then that you want to return to the first option of `switch`???

Comment: Thank you for the link to Duff's Device. Saved for later study. Not going to implement this as I assume it works just like the other goto statement posted here. I hear a lot of bad things about goto, so in an effort not to develop bad habits I will try to avoid using it if at all possible. But I really do appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
bool valid;
do
{
    char answer;
    cin >> answer;

    switch (answer)
    {
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            inventory[0] = "Short Sword";
            cout << "\nYou place the Rusty Battle Axe in the chest.";
            valid = true;
            break;

        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            inventory[0] = "Rusty Battle Axe";
            cout << "\nYou leave the Short Sword in the chest.";
            valid = true;
            break;

        default :
            cout << "\nThat was an invalid response.";
            valid = false;
            break;
    }
}
while (!valid);
```

Comment: Very good solution, the addition of the valid = checks ensures there is no infinite loop. More code than the answer just after this one, but still an excellent answer and probably closer to what an intermediate user should be doing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use a goto statement in the default section to go back to the input part

Comment: I wonder why people dont like goto. for small things like this goto wont do any harm

Comment: doesn't duff's device use a combination of loops, `goto`s and `switch`?

Comment: @paddy - Of course 'goto' is always less preferable but the OP himself is ruling out the option of using 'while' loop (which is best in these kinda situations).

Comment: I was just wondering if there was any built-in way with the switch statement to return to the first case. I have no opinions about goto statements. I just want the best possible solution, and I would like to try to avoid n00b stuff and kludges :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
bool done = false;
while (!done) {
    char answer;
    cin >> answer;
    done = true;

    switch(answer)
    {
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            inventory[0] = "Short Sword";
            cout << "\nYou place the Rusty Battle Axe in the chest.";
            break;

        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            inventory[0] = "Rusty Battle Axe";
            cout << "\nYou leave the Short Sword in the chest.";
            break;

        default :
            cout << "\nThat was an invalid response.";
            done = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use a `do..while` loop instead, particularly because the initial value of `done` is not useful since it is overwritten after reading `cin`. Set `done` to `true` if a good answer is given, and to `false` otherwise, and let the `while` of the `do..while` evaluate it after an answer is actually given rather than before asking for an answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Using a `do..while` is certainly feasible, but having to set `done` for all the right answers, seems tedious an error-prone.  Not in this case, where there are just two possibilities, but I imagine in the actual code there are many more.

Comment: This also does not work with my source code. It creates an infinite loop where you get a message, "You put the ____ in the chest." and you can keep putting your answer there forever. But I do appreciate your sharing this!

Comment: @DreamBliss: very strange.  Since `done` is set to true before the `switch`, the only way that the loop should repeat is if it hits the `default` case and then sets `done` to false.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` or `do while` loop.

Eg:

```
char answer;
bool loopback  = true;
do
{        
    cin >> answer;
    switch(answer)
    {
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            inventory[0] = "Short Sword";
            cout << "\nYou place the Rusty Battle Axe in the chest.";
            loopback  = false;
            break;

        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            inventory[0] = "Rusty Battle Axe";
            cout << "\nYou leave the Short Sword in the chest.";
            loopback  = false;
            break;

        default :
            cout << "\nThat was an invalid response.";
            loopback  = true;
    }
}
while (loopback);
```

Comment: OK this one gives me an error on the line, "while (loopback);" saying it's "...not declared in this scope." I guess technically the while part is outside the loop, so the bool inside is only in scope within the loop. Let me know if I have that wrong. Hey I'm glad you shared this, gives me an opportunity to learn something here!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `label` and `goto` statement. Label the statement where you are asking the user to input and add a `goto` statement in `default` case.
Ex::

```
AskQuestion:
 cout << "Press 'Y' for Short Sword Or 'N' for Rusty Battle Axe" << endl;
char answer;
cin >> answer;
switch(answer)
{
    case 'y':
    case 'Y':
        inventory[0] = "Short Sword";
        cout << "\nYou place the Rusty Battle Axe in the chest.";
        break;

    case 'n':
    case 'N':
        inventory[0] = "Rusty Battle Axe";
        cout << "\nYou leave the Short Sword in the chest.";
        break;

    default :
        cout << "\nThat was an invalid response.";
        goto AskQuestion ;
}
```

Alternative way is to use `do-while` loop with condition `while(answer != 'Y' || answer !=...)` as you have already commented in the question. Ex::

```
do{
 cout << "Press 'Y' for Short Sword Or 'N' for Rusty Battle Axe" << endl;
 char answer;
 cin >> answer;
 switch(answer)
 {
    case 'y':
    case 'Y':
        inventory[0] = "Short Sword";
        cout << "\nYou place the Rusty Battle Axe in the chest.";
        break;

    case 'n':
    case 'N':
        inventory[0] = "Rusty Battle Axe";
        cout << "\nYou leave the Short Sword in the chest.";
        break;

    default :
        cout << "\nThat was an invalid response.";
 }
}while( answer != 'Y' || answer != 'y' || answer != 'N' || answer != 'n' ) ;
```

Comment: @Downvoter:: Kindly leave the comment, so that the soln can be made better.

Comment: I'm not the one who down voted it. Just merely giving a suggestion. Use either the OP's code or a generic pseudo code when you post code as answer.

Comment: OK your do/while solution is not adaptable to my code. Probably because the choice is asked in an if/else statement just before. I think it would take some serious refactoring to implement this. I also feel that this is a sort of beginner's solution. I think I would like to do things closer to an intermediate or advanced skill level instead. But thank you very much for sharing it!

Comment: OK, your goto AskQuestion suggestion works very well with my code. Again, thank you!

Comment: @DreamBliss:: Just keep this in mind with respect to "GoTo":: The apprentice uses it without thinking.
The journeyman avoids it without thinking.
The master uses it thoughtfully.